# tokenize regular expression

Tags: regex, parsing

I have a string in a log I'd like to tokenize. The fields are sometimes divided by the '|' sign and sometimes by spaces.

it always looks like:
*timestamp | log_level | categroy | message_body*

or

*timestamp log_level message_body*

**example:**

```
2016/04/11 07:05:33 | INFO     | xxc        | message_message_abcde
```

Or

```
2016-04-11 07:01:24,895 INFO  message message abcde
```

What I'd like to do is remove all duplicated messages (ignore timestamp). Since I'll first grep by `log_level`=`ERROR` I can ignore `log_level` as well.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*(\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|\N+)(*SKIP)\n(?=(?:\N*\n)*?\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*\1)
```

Input:

```
2016/04/11 07:05:33 | INFO     | xxc        | message_1
2016/04/12 07:05:33 | INFO     | xxc        | message_2
2016/04/13 07:05:33 | INFO     | xxc        | message_2
2016/04/14 07:05:33 | INFO     | xxc        | message_3
2016/04/15 07:05:33 | INFO     | xxc        | message_1
```

Output:

```
2016/04/13 07:05:33 | INFO     | xxc        | message_2
2016/04/14 07:05:33 | INFO     | xxc        | message_3
2016/04/15 07:05:33 | INFO     | xxc        | message_1
```